# How to parse a PDF in Kotlin?

Tags: pdf, kotlin, pdf-parsing

Asssume we have the following [sample PDF](http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf):
[image]

In there there, on page 2, there is a text snippet `Oh, how boring typing this stuff."`
I want to print this sentence on the screen with Kotlin. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at https://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: I tried to format the question so that it becomes more accessible.

Comment: Essentially, choose a general purpose PDF library with text extraction capabilities and go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can use the iText PDF library for Android. I am using it with Kotlin Code.

https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/installation-guides/installing-itext-g-android

This library is rich for any task you want to achieve in your PDF. I am working with this library from the last 4 months.